# How do I multiply user input by multiple values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, input

I'm actually not even sure I need a dictionary I'm just not sure what else to do. Basically I need to multiply user input by multiple values. Here's what I'm working with.

```
    SmallItalian = {"Loaf of bread": .5, "Salami": .3, "Vegetables": .2, "Slices of cheese": 4}
    s_italian = input("How many small Italians were sold?")
```

I need to multiply these in order to receive something like this output:

```
    You have used ..
    16.5 loaves of bread
    1.3 lbs of Salami
    7.5 lbs of Veges
    142 slices of Cheese
    7.4 lbs of Turkey
```

Edit: So I have

```
    for amount in SmallItalian.values():
      print(SmallItalian)
```

how do I now multiply my input by my dictionary values?

Comment: A dictionary seems like a fairly reasonable structure to use here. I assume you already have the input, so next steps are to loop through the dictionary and multiple and output~!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a dictionary by it's keys, it's values or the combination of both (it's items). Simply use

```
for ingredient in Smallitalian.keys():
```

or

```
for amount in Smallitalian.values():
```

or

```
for ingredient, amount in Smallitalian.items():
```

and use the corresponding variables inside your loop. Then it should become trivial.

Using a dictionary seems okay in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to multiply every item in the dictionary by the same number as you don't make it clear. If you want to accomplish that, here is an another way that will do the trick:

```
SmallItalian = {"Loaf of bread": .5, "Salami": .3, "Vegetables": .2, "Slices of cheese": 4}
value = input("How many small Italians were sold? ")
print "You have used..."
for item in SmallItalian:
    SmallItalian[item] = SmallItalian[item] * value
    print "{} {}".format(item, SmallItalian[item])
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "TypeError: can't multiply sepquence by non-int of type 'dict'" I'm not sure how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need to preserve `SmallItalian`, you can try this :)

```
SmallItalian = {"Loaf of bread": .5, "Salami": .3, "Vegetables": .2, "Slices of cheese": 4}

outputMapping = {"Loaf of bread": "loaves of bread",
                 "Salami": "lbs of Salami",
                 "Vegetables": "lbs of Veges",
                 "Slices of cheese": "slices of Cheese"}


# need to int() it as input by default is a string
s_italian = int(input("How many small Italians were sold?"))

print("You have used ..")
# go through SmallItalian
for item, qty in SmallItalian.items():
    print(round(s_italian*qty,1), outputMapping[item])
    # round to 1d.p.
```

Output from Python shell

```
How many small Italians were sold?6
You have used ..
3.0 loaves of bread
1.8 lbs of Salami
1.2 lbs of Veges
24 slices of Cheese
>>>
```

`for item, qty in SmallItalian.items():` will iterate through the `SmallItalian` dictionary, where `item` is the key and `qty` is the value

Do let me know if this is what you are looking for :)